# Difference between if as an expression and if as a statement

Tags: go, compiler-construction, language-design

So I was watching this video on the Go language - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9VUCp98ay4 , and at around 6:50 a guy asks a question about why they implemented if's as statements and not expressions. What is the difference between those two implementations? As far as I know, I've never had to change the way I use a conditional based on the language.

Edit: and what does he mean that "you need values rather than variables" in his question?

Comment: Haven't watched in order to be able to answer the second question you asked, but to the first question, if as-an-expression would be where `x = if (condition) then { value1 } else { value2 }` can assign different values to x. Rust and Kotlin do it, for example, and it's what C's ternary operator (`?:`) does (same example is written `condition ? value1 : value2`).

Comment: It's a language design decision despite the asker's use of the word 'implementation'. If I had to guess why the Gophers designed it that way, it's that Go generally sticks to the imperative tradition of C, and blocks under `if` behaving as statements rather than like expressions is more C-like.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the BLISS programming language. You can find documentation on line. Everything is an expression in BLISS.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The difference between expressions and statements is that expressions produce a value and thus can be used in places where values are required. So expressions can be used as values for variables, arguments to functions or operands to operators. Statements can't.

> and what does he mean that "you need values rather than variables" in his question?

I assume that by vals he means constants (which are called `val`s in Scala for example).

If `if` were an expression, you could do this:

```
const myValue = if condition { value1 } else { value2 }
```

Since `if` is not an expression, you have to do this:

```
var myValue
if condition {
    myValue = value1
} else {
    myValue = value2
}
```

So you needed to make your variable mutable (use `var` instead of `const`), which is what the person asking the question likely meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same code elegance that you would get from if expression by using an instantly invoked function (IIF) combined with if statements in GO. I'm not a GO programmer (mainly typescript) so please let me know if this is bad for performance for any reason.

```golang
func main() {
    amIHungry := true
    didMyPaycheckComeInYet := false

    choice := func() string {
        if(!amIHungry && !didMyPaycheckComeInYet){
            return "stay-home"
        }
        if(!amIHungry && didMyPaycheckComeInYet){
            return "buy-new-keyboard"
        }
        if(amIHungry && !didMyPaycheckComeInYet){
            return "make-ramen"
        }
        return "taco-bell-time"
    }()

    println(choice)

}
```

and then later on in your program, rather than having a bunch of out of context states, you can have a simplified "choice" to choose your app logic.

```golang
if(choice == "taco-bell-time"){
   println("Order a bean burrito, but with black beans,")
}
```

is a little easier to reason about than

```golang
if(amIHungry && didMyPaycheckComeInYet){
     println("Order a bean burrito, but with black beans,")
}
```